# Array of PSCustomObjects as input parameter

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameter-passing

Recently I'm stuck with the issue of providing an array of arrays as input parameter for the PS script.

I have two scripts. One is to start and manage processes and the second one is to execute certain actions on computers provided as input parameter.

It's successfully working when I submit one PC over `-Computer` parameter

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
       ParameterSetName="input1",
       HelpMessage="Privide single computer name")]
       [alias("host","workstation")]
       [string]$Computer=$env:COMPUTERNAME,
```

or over `-InputFile` parameter

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
       ParameterSetName="input3",
       HelpMessage="Privide full path to input file which contains list of hosts")]
       [ValidatePattern("^.*\.(TXT|txt|CSV|csv)")]
       [alias("file","input")]
       [string]$InputFile,
```

However I have another input parameter when I want to submit an array. Parameter name is `-Computers`:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
       ParameterSetName="input2",
       HelpMessage="Privide array of computers")]
       [alias("hosts","workstations")]
       [string[]]$Computers,
```

In the first script where I start processes and managed them I use following:

```
#Define arguments for executable 
$PSArguments = $null
$PSArguments += "-WindowStyle Normal "
$PSArguments += "-Command `"$Script_DPNE "
$PSArguments += "-Computers $Package`""

#Prepare process
$Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute  = $False
$Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = "Hidden"
$Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = $True
$Process.StartInfo.FileName  = $Executable
$Process.StartInfo.Arguments = $PSArguments

#Start process
$Process.Start() | Out-Null
```

Unfortunately `$package` which is an array is not passed.
`$Package` have following structure:

```
Hostname   param1    param2
--------   ------    ------
host1      1         1
host2      0         1
host3      1         1
host4      1         0
```

etc..

param1 and param2 can contain only 0 or 1

How can I pass such an array into the script?

Comment: Um, what command do you try to run? If you're trying to launch another Powershell script, you should instead use `&` operator to run a script. Otherwise an attempt to pass an array via command line will have it turned to a plain string, since command line processing is unaware of Powershell types, arrays etc.

Comment: I'm trying to run another powershell script. Resulting command is like `powershell.exe -WindowStyle Normal -Command "E:\secondscript.ps1 -Computers <here should be an array>"`

Comment: The other thing is that I prefer  to use System.Diagnostics.Process class cause later on in the script I manged started processes which is several in parallel.
Then solution could be to pass this array as string like `@{...}` and then convert back to array in secondscript.ps1.
Is this make sense?

Comment: So, you need to do something in parallel - okay, add `-AsJob` to the parameter list. If you insist on creating new processes, you'll then have to serialize the array into a command line, which isn't as easy as it sounds. What you speak is sensible, but I am yet unaware if doable out of the box.

Comment: Is $package really an array of arrays?  Or is it an array of hashtables?

Comment: Sorry `$package` is array of PSCustomObjects  `$package[0].GetType()` >> PSCustomObject

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution which is working for me.
I convert $Package which is array of PSCustomObjects into string like:

@([pscustomobject]@{Hostname="";Param1=;Param2=},...)